# How to gain data from recursive function?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I've created a recursive function which returns the best price for you can sell apples on market. Since it is much more simple to explain this problem on real world thing, I'm going to explain it on buyers and apples.

There are three buyers. Each buyer is willing to pay different price for different apple.

There must be `3*n` apples because you have to sell the same amount of apples to all (three) buyers.

The function finds the best possible sell.

For example: `apples = [[1,50,1], [1,50,1], [1,1,50]]` means that there are three buyers and three apples.

The first apple (`apples[0]`) can be sold to 1st buyer (`apples[0][0]`) for 1 dollar, to 2nd buyer for 50 dollars and 3rd buyer for 1 dollar.

(function returns 101 which is correct, you can't distribute those three apples earning more money)

This function works great but it counts the result (how much money you earn). I want to know which apple I have to sell to which buyer to earn maximum amount of money. It is somewhere there but I can't figure out how to get it from the function because it's recursive and until the recursion is not on last level, you don't know which results do you have to count with.

```
apples = [[1,50,1], [1,50,1], [1,1,50]]

def sell_apples(buyer1, buyer2, buyer3):
    global results
    if (buyer1,buyer2,buyer3) in results.keys():
         return results[(buyer1,buyer2,buyer3)]

        n = sum([buyer1, buyer2, buyer3])
        if buyer1 == buyer2 == buyer3 == 0 or n == 0:
            return 0
        os = []
        for i in range(3):
            buyers = [buyer1, buyer2, buyer3]
            if buyers[i] > 0:
                buyers[i] -= 1
                os.append(sell_apples(*buyers) + apples[n - 1][i]) # here are possible parts of results
        m = max(os)
        results[(buyer1,buyer2,buyer3)]=m
        return m


print sell_apples(1,1,1)
```

returns 101 which is correct. But I want to get something like this: `[(0,1),(1,0),(2,2)]` which means that the best result you have when you sell first apple to second buyer, second apple to first buyer and third apple to third buyer.

It can be somehow obtained from `apples[n-1][i]` but there are all options here, not just those I want.

Comment: Could you explain what do you need? in short words please.. I dont understand

Comment: I want to know the best combination (which apples have to be sold to which buyers). Now, the function returns the best possible price.

Comment: for example apples = [[1,50,1], [1,50,1], [1,80,50]] >> should return 110 ?  :S

Comment: No, it would be 101. Because it's the maximum you can get. You sell the firs apple to second buyer [0][1], the second apple to first buyer [1][0] and the third apple to third buyer [2][2]. It's the best sell you can get from it.

Comment: Since you have to sell the same amount of apples to each buyer, I you've sold the second apple to third buyer (for 80 dollars), you would have to sell another apples for 1 dollar since you have not another option.

Comment: Milor123: I can't solve that, I'm trying to but I didn't find a way. Maybe I know what approach would be better (from googling and chatting with SO users). The best would be to convert this TopDown approach to BottomUp because it's simpler to get additional informations like which apples has been sold to which buyer, when you user bottom up.

Comment: I've read again the problem, but think I'm missing, do you have a text or example about problem? Sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110080/discussion-between-milor123-and-lemmy).

Answer (score 0):

Probably recursion is not the best way of solving this problem, as it looks like there will be a lot if intermediate results recalculated. You have mitigated this problem by caching these results. Instead you could try to structure the problem bottom up, to first calculate the best results for the smaller problems and keep them in a table. Since you keep the results in a table, it will also be easier to track the final solution instead of just the score.

The funny thing is, that this bottom-up approach with keeping intermediate results is called "dynamic programming", which you mention in the tags, but then do not use in your program. There are some good examples around for dynamic programming algorithms, e.g. for the knapsack problem or the Viterbi algorithm and (for a very basic example) calculating Fibonacci numbers.

A quick fix to your problem would be to keep track of the buyers configuration each time you return from the function.

Comment: It's for dynamic programming purposes. I've edited the code with dynamic programming approach which decreases the amount of recalculations to zero probably. I was thinking about bottom up approach but couldn't figure out anything what would suit with dynamic programming.

Comment: I'm saving each result of function call into dictionary called results and I try to find it in the dictionary first.

Comment: I'm trying but I can't figure out the bottom-up approach. There are so many combinations when you have n*3 apples. I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: Thank you very much Hans, so this can be considered as dynamic programming? Is it bottom-up? From what I've found I think that yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns just the same as input: sell_apples(2,2,2) with 6 apples returns result and (2,2,2)  (the 2 is a number of apples remains for the buyer).

Comment: Yes, I mistook the function of your buyers variable. So you need to keep track of which buyer buys which apple in each of the solutions. I am not sure if your solution would qualify as dynamic programming however. I am not entirely sure that I get the full logic behind it.